# divs appear above the footer instead of inside the footer

Tags: html, css

I am just practicing CSS/HTML and am trying to make a google clone. Everything else seems fine but now I am trying to make a footer and whenever I put a div inside the footer, they appear on top of the footer instead of inside the footer.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;700&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    background-color: rgb(32, 33, 36);
    color: white;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

.nav-bar a:nth-child(1):hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.nav-bar a:nth-child(2):hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}


.nav-bar {
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.nav-items {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-items li {
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.menu-icon {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.menu-icon:hover {
    background-color: rgba(138, 133, 133, 0.26);
}

.menu-icon span {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
}

.profile-picture {
    margin-right: 15px;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.profile-picture:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px #7068683b;
}

.profile-picture img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}

.main-section {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 80px;
}

.google-logo {
    width: 375px;
    height: 150px;
}

.google-logo img {
    width: 100%;
}

.search-section {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.search-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 580px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: #949090;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 300px;
    padding: 9px;
    height: 45px;
}

.search-container:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px #00000036;
}

.search-icon {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.search-icon img {
    width: 100%;
}

.search-bar {
    width: 550px;
    height: 30px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

.microphone {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}

.microphone img {
    width: 100%;
}

.search-buttons {
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.search-buttons button {
    margin-left: 6px;
    padding: 10px 16px 10px 16px;
    background-color: #303134;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #e8eaed;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: solid 1px transparent;
}

.search-buttons button:hover {
    border-color: #e8eaed;
}

.language-selector {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.language-selector p {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #bdc1c6;
}

.language-selector a {
    color: #8ab4f8;
}

.footer {
    background-color: #446adb;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 92px;  
}
```

```html
<body>
    <!-- start of the navigation bar-->
    <nav class="nav-bar">
        <ul class="nav-items">
            <li><a href="#">Gmail</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">სურათები</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="menu-icon">
                        <span>
                        </span>
                        <span>
                        </span>
                        <span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><div class="profile-picture">
                    <img src="icons/unnamed.png">
                </div></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- end of the navigation bar -->

    <!-- start of the main section (logo and search-bar)-->
    <div class="main-section">
        <a href="#"><div class="google-logo">
            <img src="icons/google.png">
        </div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="search-section">
        <div class="search-container">
            <div class="search-icon"><img src="icons/search.png"/></div>
            <input type="text" class="search-bar">
            <div class="microphone"><img src="icons/micro.png" alt=""></div>
        </div>
        <div class="search-buttons">
            <button>
                Google ძებნა
            </button>
            <button>
                იღბალს მივენდობი
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="language-selector">
        <p>Google ხელმისაწვდომია შემდეგ ენაზე: <a href="#">English</a></p>
    </div>
    <!-- end of the main section -->

    <!-- start of the footer-->
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="current-location">
            this text should be inside the footer
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

here is the picture of the problem I am having.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXMv6.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is inside the footer. Just this property:

```
background-color: rgb(32, 33, 36);
```

which you set for `*` gets inherited, and the bg color makes you think text it outside the footer. Comment it out for a while and you will see.